# Where should Google Refine / OpenRefine questions go?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, scope

Google Refine is currently moving to GitHub and being renamed to OpenRefine. The community is looking for a place to host Q&A (currently maintained in a discussion list). Google Refine already has a [google-refine](/questions/tagged/google-refine) tag open on Stack Overflow and a few appearances on Stats.StackExchange.

Regarding the fact that OpenRefine generates both tech and non-tech questions due to its [wide variety of users and usages](http://googlerefine.blogspot.ca/2012/10/google-refine-usage-survey-results.html), can we direct all question on Stack Overflow? Is there another place where OpenRefine questions could be asked, or would one need to be created?